# Unable to find a function in R

Tags: r, rasterizing

I have been using this function for a while now. It is weird that all of the sudden the fun=mean is not working for raster package of R!!

```
rasterize(data_r[,1:2], r, data_r[,3], fun=mean)

Error in .pointsToRaster(x, y, field = field, fun = fun, background = background,  : 
  could not find function "fun"
```

However, anything other than mean is working; e.g. fun = 'sum' seems to work fine! Any idea?

Comment: what version are you using? Always update first, and report sessionInfo()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine here:

```
Rgames> rasterize(matrix(1:6,3)/6,raster(matrix(1:8,4)/8),fun=mean)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 4, 2, 8  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1, 3  (min, max)
```

Did you check to be sure you haven't accidentally removed `mean` from your environment, or overwritten it w/ something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have accidentally created another function with the name `mean`, you can still access the original function in its namespace, i.e., `base`, using `base::mean`.

```
rasterize(data_r[,1:2], r, data_r[,3], fun = base::mean)
```